How Does Jenkins extend/compile/run Plugins?
I try to create a plugin-based-app and I saw similar service on Jenkins. It allows to create plugins in .jpi/.hpi format and then upload/install this plugin. But I couldn't figure its-pipeline out from source code.
When I trace the source-code I saw just a file-replacement in deep:
    public void install(DownloadJob job, File src, File dst) throws IOException {
        job.replace(dst, src);
    }

So I couldn't figure it out, any help, any suggestion?
